# Cant read post from Fetch in node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, fetch-api

I'm posting the data `{id: "abc123", text: "sometext"}` to a node API. Posting from a component with `action` call:

```
export function addTextToAPI(inputData) {
    return(dispatch) => {
        console.log(inputData),
        dispatch(addText(inputData))
         fetch(myapi, { 
            headers: {
               'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            data:  inputData
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
    }
}
```

console.log(inputData) is `{id: "abc123", text: "sometext"}`

**node:**

```
var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/addtest', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body);        // <= returns blank object {}

    console.log(req.body.data);   // <= returns undefined

    console.log(req.query);       // <= returns blank object {}

    console.log("test added");      

});


app.listen(3000);
```

I want to be able to read the `inputData` in `req`. How do I do that? I want to be able to read the `inputData` in `req`. How do I do that?

Comment: I've also tried `JSON.stringify(inputdata)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is your content-type request header?

Comment: @Phix .. Updated the `fetch` in question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To post data you need to pass in a `body` param to fetch.

This should work:

```
export function addTextToAPI(inputData) {
    return(dispatch) => {
        console.log(inputData),
        dispatch(addText(inputData))
         fetch(myapi, { 
            headers: {
               'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(inputData)
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
    }
}
```

Comment: passing `body` doesn't work. Now I'm not even getting any `console logs` from node. Changing back to `data` console log is working. I thing passing `body` doesn't call node at all.

Comment: try `JSON.stringify` ing `inputData` and passing it as body

Comment: That worked! `JSON.stringify` did the trick. Why do I need to add `body` and can't pass it like any other `param`?

Comment: This is in the fetch [spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#bodies), meaning it is just how the api is designed - you have to pass a `body`.